# Opencv with picamera and haar cascades python

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi2, haar-classifier

***Hi I'm trying to detect cars using PiCamera and Haar Cascade but ran into errors.***

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from picamera import PiCamera
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
import time
import io
from picamera.array import PiYUVArray

car_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cars3.xml')

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32

rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))
time.sleep(0.1)

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="rgb", use_video_port=True):
         image = frame.array

while 1:
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    cars = car_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in cars:
        cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]


        cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
        rawCapture.truncate(0)
        rawCapture.seek(0)

        if key == ord("q"):
                break



cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

***After running the above codes I got these errors***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 18, in <module>
    for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="rgb", use_video_port=True):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1851, in capture_continuous
    if not encoder.wait(self.CAPTURE_TIMEOUT):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 850, in wait
    self.stop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 881, in stop
    self._close_output()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 795, in _close_output
    output.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/array.py", line 285, in flush
    self.array = bytes_to_rgb(self.getvalue(), self.size or self.camera.resolution)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/array.py", line 174, in bytes_to_rgb
    'Incorrect buffer length for resolution %dx%d' % (width, height))
picamera.exc.PiCameraValueError: Incorrect buffer length for resolution 640x480
```

***I suspect it's because of** `camera.capture_continuous` **which I need to insert** `rawCapture.truncate(0)` **and** `rawCapture.seek(0)` **below it to work. 
But when I insert both these lines under** `camera.capture_continuous` **I would need to insert** `cv2.imshow("Frame", image)` **below too or else the frame will not show. However if I did that, my haar cascades codes get ignore and do not work. I just started on coding recently so my assumption may be wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated thank you.***